# ListView List With SubItems

Tags: c#, list, listview

Okay, how do I programmatically add items from an `List<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>` to an `ListView`? I am trying to load 3 lists of items next to each other, but it doesn't seem to work...

Here's some code I have right now:

```
    //----------PluginHandler.cs----------/

public static List<ListViewItem> PluginList = new List<ListViewItem>();
public static List<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem> PluginList2 = new List<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>();

PluginList.Clear();
PluginList2.Clear();
foreach (var item in plugin.versions)
{
    var lvitem = new ListViewItem { Text = item.name };
    var lvitem2 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem { Text = item.filename };
    PluginList.Add(lvitem);
    PluginList2.Add(lvitem2);
}

    //----------Form1.cs----------/

lvPluginInfo.Items.AddRange(PluginHandler.PluginList.ToArray());
lvPluginInfo.Items[0].SubItems.AddRange(PluginHandler.PluginList2.ToArray());
```

The output I get isn't really what I want, it keeps adding subitems to the right instead of adding them next to eachother like:

item1a |  item2a
item1b |  item2b
...

Now I get:
item1a |  item2a | item1b | item2b | ...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be going about this in a very odd fashion.  I assume this is what you're intending to do?

```
lvPluginInfo.Items.Clear();
foreach (var item in plugin.versions)
{
    var lvitem = new ListViewItem(item.name);
    lvitem.SubItems.Add(item.filename);
    lvPluginInfo.Items.Add(lvitem);
}
```

The problem with the way you're going about it is the following line: `lvPluginInfo.Items[0].SubItems.AddRange(PluginHandler.PluginList2.ToArray());`.  You're adding all the subitems to the first ListViewItem.  Adding the items outside of the loop doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: You could.  You could create a public method on the class (I assume a `Form`?) called `UpdatePluginList()` that contained the above logic.  You could call this method on an instance of the form from another class.